# complex query to get total balance for each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying following query to get total balance and date to use in bar chart, and its working but returning 2 entries for same date if there are 2 entries with using that date, but i want to group those dates in 1 date...

mysql query...

```
SELECT dnt, 
@running_bal := @running_bal + (`Credit` - `Debit`)  as `Balance`
FROM transactions, (SELECT @running_bal := 0) tempName
ORDER BY dnt ASC
```

Example results...

```
+----------------------+-----------+
|         dnt          |  Balance  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| 2014-03-06 10:30:00  | 28350.00  |
| 2014-03-06 10:30:00  | 29295.00  |
| 2014-03-13 09:30:00  | 57645.00  |
| 2014-03-13 09:30:00  | 85995.00  |
| 2014-03-17 09:30:00  | 114345.00 |
| 2014-03-20 09:30:00  | 134190.00 |
| 2014-03-26 20:02:30  | 133690.00 |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT dnt, 
   @running_bal := @running_bal + `Balance` as `Balance`
FROM 
  (SELECT dnt, SUM(Credit) - SUM(Debit) as `Balance` FROM transactions GROUP BY dnt) tmp,
  (SELECT @running_bal := 0) tempName
ORDER BY dnt ASC
```

Comment: Thanks but getting this error... `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: thanks, it solved my issue. I will accept this answer, and let me know if you are available for smaller mysql projects.